# Java frame.dispose(); not working

Tags: java, swing, debugging, intellij-idea, jframe

Can anyone guide me on why 'frame.dispose();' doesn't dispose the frame? The other method is called but 'frame.dispose();' is just ignored. This java class is used to check whether a stored answer that is made from another java class (RecoveryQuestion.check()) is the same as the user's input. Public variables such as StoredQuestion and StoredPassword are in the RecoveryQuestion class as well. Furthermore, I'm using Intelli J IDEA GUI form and I don't know how to extract the code, however, the form runs smoothly as intended except with the frame.dispose();

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ForgotPassword {
private JPanel panel1;
private JTextField answer;
private JLabel Question;
private JButton Submit;
private JFrame frame = new JFrame("Password Reset");

public ForgotPassword() {



    Submit.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            if(RecoveryQuestion.StoredPassword.equals(answer.getText())) {
                //frame.dispatchEvent(new WindowEvent(frame, WindowEvent.WINDOW_CLOSING));
                frame.dispose();
                FirstRun.main(null);



            }
            else JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Incorrect Answer");

        }
    });
}

public void setUI() {


    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setContentPane(new ForgotPassword().panel1);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(400,250));
    frame.pack();
    frame.setResizable(false);




}

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try{
        RecoveryQuestion.Check();
    } catch(IOException e1) {}

    new ForgotPassword().setUI();
}

private void createUIComponents() {
    // TODO: place custom component creation code here
    Question = new JLabel();
    Question.setText(RecoveryQuestion.StoredQuestion);
}
```

}

Comment: Please see edits to answer and ask if any questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every call to `new ForgotPassword()` does just that -- it creates a completely new and unique ForgotPassword instance. Look at your code above, and count how many times that you call this -- I see two times, suggesting that your problem is that you're displaying a JFrame from one of these instances, and trying to dispose of it in another -- two different JFrames that are unrelated to each other.

Suggestions:

- Your code is very convoluted with instances creating instances of them self within their self. Simplify.
- Create only **one** ForgotPassword in your GUI and pass it where needed
- Side issue: shouldn't this sort of window be a dialog window (i.e., a JDialog) and not an application window (i.e., a JFrame)?
- If your code did work as intended, then calling `.dispose()` on this JFrame should cause the JVM to exit (the entire program to end) since you're setting its default close operation to `EXIT_ON_CLOSE`.
- Side issue 2: your posted code is not a valid [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) meaning we cannot easily copy the code, paste it into our IDE and compile and run it without modification, making it more difficult for us to fully understand your code and forcing me to guess at your problem. In the future (and now), please consider posting  one of these. Note that we **do not want to see your entire program**, nor should you post a link to a code repository. Instead keep it small, keep it simple, and make it functioning.